# Linking target with multiple object files in BSD make

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to write a simple and portable `Makefile` that can be processed with both `gmake` and `bmake`, so i decided to stick with implicit suffix rules as most reliable way to avoid syntax incompatibilities, e.g. `$^` and `$>` variables for all target prerequesites. They also share a common set of variables such as `CFLAGS`, `CPPFLAGS`, `LDFLAGS` and `LDLIBS`.

The project is `dwm` and the final target is `dwm` executable that compiles from `dwm.c` and that also needs to be linked with `util.o` and `drw.o` object files.

My first attempt was the rule like this:

```
dwm: util.o drw.o
dwm: LDLIBS += -lX11 -lXft -lfontconfig
```

I didn't specify any build rules, just set the FLAGs, and this works perfectly with GNU `make`. BSD's one gives almost the same commands with the exception that last command seems like this:

```bash
cc -pipe -g -std=c99 -pedantic -Wno-deprecated-declarations -I/usr/include/freetype2 -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE -D_BSD_SOURCE -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700L -DVERSION=\"6.4\"  -o dwm dwm.c -lX11 -lXft -lfontconfig
```

i.e. the `drw.o` and `util.o` are missing even though they were built before.

The reason is that BSD `make` uses only `${.IMPSRC}` (or `$<`) for `.c` suffix rule, but then i don't really understand how to implement that simplest use case without writing a custom linking rule for each target. And please note that I have no problem building the project, I'm just learning about `make`.

Comment: What happens if you add `dwm.o` explicitly to the dependencies for `dwm` (the first line in your makefile).  That should not hurt anything in gmake.

Comment: @ChrisDodd the problem is the same, the only difference is that is need to compile dwm.o from multiple sources to avoid getting errors about undefined references

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with BSD make.  However, if the default suffix rule for binaries uses only `$<` (or the equivalent), then it's broken and you'll have to replace it.  You can (should be able to) just replace it with something like:

```
.o:
        $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)
```

Comment: I mentioned this - it breaks portability, because the variable containing all the target prerequisites is $^ and $> in gmake and bmake.

Comment: _I mentioned this_ -- not really.  If BSD make doesn't provide `$^` then the only thing I can suggest is creating a `GNUmakefile` in your directory that assigns the special BSD make variables to their GNU make counterparts, then use the BSD variables everywhere.

Comment: $^ and ^> are rule scoped variables, they are set by make itself

Comment: Of course.  But you can do something like `.IMPSRC = $<` then when someone uses `$(.IMPSRC)` it will expand to the current value of `$<`.  At least, that's try in any POSIX-compliant implementation.

Comment: Well i did something like this, but inside the main Makefile with `.ALLSRC ?= $^`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the workaround:

```
.ALLSRC ?= $^
.TARGET ?= $@

.c:
    ${LINK.c} -o ${.TARGET} ${.ALLSRC} ${LDLIBS}

.c.o:
    ${COMPILE.c} -o ${.TARGET} ${.ALLSRC}
```

The key is to conditionally assign `bmake` specific `.ALLSRC` variable  to `^`, which is the `gmake` equivalent. Then it is possible to build the binary linked with all dependencies, like this:

```
dwm: util.o drw.o
```

or you can specify only the sources and build the binary right away:

```
dwm: util.c drw.c
```

You also may want to redefine `LINK.c` and `COMPILE.c` in your `Makefile`, but this is optional. And the assignment to `.TARGET` is just for consistency.